# Best way to render seat plan

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to dynamically render a seat plan in a winforms app. I'm not sure the best way to handle this.

I did initially start of with this

```
        string[] blocks = new string[6] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
        int[] rows = new int[6] { 10, 6, 6, 10, 8, 8 };
        int[] seats = new int[6] { 15, 10, 10, 15, 25, 25 };
```

forgetting that it would just loop through the rows and seats arrays for the size of the arrays. I actually need to render out a differing number of seats per row and a different number of rows per blocks.

So in the code sample above; Block A has 10 rows with each row having 15 seats. Block B has 6 rows, with each row having 10 seats, etc, etc

My code renders out a label control for each seat.

Comment: and the question is... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hm, first you should create a struct:

```
public struct Block
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public int Rows { get; set; }
 public int Seats { get; set; }
}
```

second fill the data as List:

```
List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>
{
 new Block { Name = "A", Rows = 10, Seats = 15 },
 new Block { Name = "B", Rows =  6, Seats = 10 },
 new Block { Name = "C", Rows =  6, Seats = 10 },
 new Block { Name = "D", Rows = 10, Seats = 15 },
 new Block { Name = "E", Rows =  8, Seats = 25 },
 new Block { Name = "F", Rows =  8, Seats = 25 },
};
```

and drawing or create Form Controls, cheap labels as example:

```
int selectedIndex = 3;

Block block = blocks[selectedIndex];

this.Text = "Block: " + block.Name; // Window Title = "Block: D"

for (int y = 0; y < block.Rows; y++)
{
 for (int x = 0; x < block.Seats; x++)
 {
  Label label = new Label();
  label.Left = x * 50;
  label.Top = y * 20;
  label.Width = 50;
  label.Height = 20;
  label.Text = "[" + (y + 1) + ", " + (x + 1) + "]";
  this.Controls.Add(label);
 }
}
```

for better answers ask more precise questions ;-)